# Can't navigate to other screen from the screen in TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

I trying to render StackNavigator inside TabNavigator. The Tabs are working fine, but i cannot link the button

In simple words, there's a button inside the "Feed" section of the TabNavigator "Tabs" . When clicked on the button, it should go to "UserDetails.js" via StackNavigator.
Please help!

Here is my index.android.js

```js
export default class HackernoonNavigation extends Component {
  render() {
    return (  
      <Tabs />
    );
  }
}

export const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Feed: {
    screen: Feed,
  },
  Me: {
    screen: Me,
  },
});
```

And here is the file "Feed.js" , inside which there is a button that leads to "UserDetail.js"

```js
export default class Feed extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to Feed!
        </Text>
         <Button
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
          title="User Details"
        />
      </View>
    );
  } 
}

export const FeedStack = StackNavigator({
  Details: { screen: UserDetail },
});
```

Comment: How are you importing `Feed`?

Comment: Where do you use `FeedStack`?

Comment: Have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by defining tabnavigator inside stacknavigator as screen like in this way -

```
 const StackNaviApp = StackNavigator({
 UserDetails: { screen: UserDetails},
 Feed: {
  screen: TabNavigator({
    Feed: { screen: Feed},
    Me: { screen: Me}

  }, {
    tabBarOptions: { 
      showIcon: true,
      lazy: true,

      activeTintColor: '#7567B1',
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '600'
      }
    }
  })
  }});
  export default StackNaviApp;
```

Taking Feed & Me inside TabNavigator & UserDetails inside StackNavigator directly . For more detail you can refer the source code from here -

http://androidseekho.com/others/reactnative/switching-between-stack-navigator-to-tab-navigator/

Answer (score 0):

So I have a ListView on a Tab Screen and when I click on the List Item its navigating to a component called QR Code. So when I click a List Item the camera will be opened in a new window with StackNavigator.... I show you my code down below. Maybe it helps you to find your fault.

```
  import React, {
        Component,
    } from 'react';
    import {
        // AppRegistry,
        // Dimensions,
        ListView,
        StyleSheet,
        Text,
        TouchableOpacity,
        TouchableHighlight,
        View,
        AsyncStorage
    } from 'react-native';

    import { SwipeListView, SwipeRow } from 'react-native-swipe-list-view';
    import moment from 'moment';
    import{createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
    import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'

    import QrCode from '../components/QrCode';

    class SwipeList extends Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
            title: 'Scanner auswählen',
            headerTintColor: 'white',
            headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#444444'},
            headerTitleStyle: { color: 'white' },
          };

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
            this.state = {
                scannerAvailable:false,
                listType: 'FlatList',
                listViewData: this.ds,
        }
    ...
        goToQrCodeScreen=(scanner)=>{
           this.props.navigation.navigate('QrCode',{
                scannerName: scanner.scannerName,
                scannerValidityEnd: scanner.scannerValidityEnd,
                scannerId: scanner.scannerId,
                dataMacroId: scanner.dataMacroId,
                hash:scanner.hash,
                requestKey: scanner.requestKey,
                })
        }

    ...
        render() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>


                    <View>
                    <SwipeListView
                        dataSource={this.state.listViewData}
                        renderRow={ data => (
                            <View >
                                <TouchableHighlight 
                                onPress={()=>this.goToQrCodeScreen(data)}
                                style={styles.rowFront}
                                        underlayColor={'#AAA'}>

                                    <Text>  <Text style={[styles.listItemName,styles.textBold] } >{data.scannerName} </Text>
                                    <Text style={styles.listItemValid}> gültig bis {moment(data.scannerValidityEnd).format('DD.MM.YYYY')}</Text>
                                    </Text>
                                </TouchableHighlight>
                            </View>
                        )}
                        renderHiddenRow={ (data, secId, rowId, rowMap) => (
                            <View style={styles.rowBack}>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.backRightBtn, styles.backRightBtnRight]} onPress={ _ => this.deleteRow(data.scannerId,rowMap, `${secId}${rowId}`) }>
                                <Icon
                                name='trash'
                                type='font-awesome'
                                color='white'/>
                                <Text style={styles.backTextWhite}>
                                    Löschen</Text> 
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        )}

                        rightOpenValue={-100}
                        enableEmptySections={true}
                     />
            </View>

                    </View>
            );
        }
    }


const StackNavigation = createStackNavigator(
    {
    SwipeList:SwipeList ,
    QrCode:QrCode
    },

    {
        initialRouteName: 'SwipeList',
      }
  );



export default StackNavigation;
```

I deleted the code you dont need. I call the method goToQrCodeScreen() to navigate. 
My fault was that I dont exported the StackNavigator. Now its working.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your feed in another component :

```
const FeedStack = createStackNavigator();

function FeedWrapper() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <FeedStack .Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <FeedStack .Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation